# Help with payment_status PayPal Refunded Reversed Partially Refuned IPNs

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

Will this script below work with the IPN Messages Sent with IPNs if the member is on a subscription and/or pay once payment and they request a Refund, Reversal, or Partial Refund?

```
if($payment_status == "Refunded" || $payment_status == "Reversed" || $payment_status == "Partially Refunded"){
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET month_date = '$gettoday', subscr_id = '$subscr_id', subscr_cancel = 'Y', active = 'N', prepay = 'N' WHERE id='$id'");
}
```

If not, what can I use or how do I script it in PHP to make my system read the IPN payment_status of all and know what subscriber (by their PayPal Subscribe ID or Member ID in my system) or payer ((By their Member ID in my system) to perform actions on when one of these are sent?

Also, If I wanted to check for a subscribe ID will it be smarter to do it like this?

```
if($payment_status == "Refunded" || $payment_status == "Reversed" || $payment_status == "Partially Refunded"){

if($subscr_id){

mysql_query("UPDATE members SET month_date = '$gettoday', subscr_id = '$subscr_id', subscr_cancel = 'Y', active = 'N', prepay = 'N' WHERE id='$id'");

} else {

mysql_query("UPDATE members SET month_date = '$gettoday', subscr_cancel = 'Y', active = 'N', prepay = 'N' WHERE id='$id'");

}}
```

Comment: questions like "will this work" are best answered yourself by testing.  1.you learn more. 2. there are a million settings that can be different between set ups, so works for me may not mean work for you.

Comment: Any help will be good though. When I get one working the others don't. I've had a refund here and there and my system didn't perform the code I put. That's why I'm reaching out to other talented developers to get help. I wouldn't be posting here if I wanted to figure it out without help. Any assistance is welcomed. The only bad question is the one not asked.

Comment: actully the faq has a list of bad questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paypal will first send an IPN that the payment status is reversed, followed by another IPN with the status refunded. So, I would not include both reversed and refunded as you did in your original example.

As for testing for the user_id, that's always consistent, every IPN includes the payers paypal email including the reversed/refunded messages.

Comment: Wow I didn't know that before. Is there any article on the web related to this? It seems so easy to trip over it.

Comment: Is this definitely true? That `Refunded` always goes after `Reversed`?

Comment: I have recently encountered exactly this situation in a production PayPal IPN integration. There were 21 days (give or take 2 hours) in between the `Reversed` IPN message and the `Refunded` IPN message.

Comment: Guys, massive THANK YOU from CANADA.  It's now 2023 and I was banging my head working on a solution with webhooks for reversal as I could not find any id correlation (not knowing this).  Refund does come after Reversal according this article published by Paypal:  https://www.paypal.com/us/brc/article/bank-reservals-guide which I would not have found without your input here.  Thanks again, really.  :-)