# PayPal IPN message: what is the difference between Reversed and Refunded?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am interested about the difference between `Reversed` and `Refunded` values for `payment_status` on IPN messages? I saw an official description on [PayPal IPN variables page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/), but I don't understand the difference. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5226886/1972266) `Refunded` is called after `Reversed`. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

- refunded: you refunded it
- reversed: PayPal reversed it on a dispute. If you win the dispute this is followed by cancel-reverse.

Comment: Ok. But is `Refunded` called after `Reversed`?

Comment: Sigh. Refunded: *you* refunded the money. Reversed: *PayPal* took the money back. They are completely different events. Not one before the other.

Comment: Did you check that? Why than [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5226886/1972266) says `Refunded` goes also after `Reversed`?